# Value is returned as None from function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the value of an user input defined key from nested dictionary.
While I am able to print out the value from the function itself. Return statement sends value as None.

```
people = {1: {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male'},
          2: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female'},
          3: 'James',
          4: 'lance',
          'change1': {5: 'place'},
          'country': {'Waterloo': 'Waterloo', 'Australia': 'Australia'},
          6: {'Position': 'GM'}
          }

def getfromdict(mydict, mykey):
    for i in mydict.keys():

        if type(mydict[i])==dict:
            newdict = mydict[i]
            getfromdict(newdict, mykey)

        elif i == mykey:
            print(mydict[i])
            valuefound = mydict[i]
            return valuefound

        else:
            continue

result = getfromdict(people,5)
print(result)
```

Comment: This is the output of code execution: --> place
None

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: have you tried my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to search the keys in the nested JSON

```
 def getfromdict(mydict, mykey):
    if type(mydict) == type({}):
        for k1 in mydict:
            if k1 == mykey:
                return mydict[k1]
            fromdict = getfromdict(mydict[k1], mykey)
            if fromdict is not None:
                return fromdict
```

Comment: can you mark this solution as answered, because the other solution is misleading is misleading

Answer (score 2):

Line three of your code snippet should read

```
           return getfromdict(newdict, mykey)
```

To find a leaf in a tree, well, you can, for istance,

```
def leaf(tree, key):
    if key in tree: return tree[key]
    for subtree in filter(lambda s: isinstance(s, dict), tree.values()):
        ret_val = leaf(subtree, key)
        if ret_val is not None: return ret_val
```

This implementation has the property that if a key is found at some level, whatever it points to is returned, either a leaf or a subtree (in undesired, a fix is quite straightforward).

Comment: have you tried running the code, it won't work as it will get excited in the first nested loop itself